# jquery().html() is not working after AJAX call in IE

Tags: html, jquery

i have fallowing code

```
url = "./orderMaintenance.cso?searchLabel=addLineItemController&soNum=" + soNum;
    $.post(url,$('#ordMaintForm').serialize(), function(responseValue) {    
    if(!checkSessionExpiry(responseValue)) {   
       //alert("responseValue:::"+responseValue)
       $('#contentarea').html(responseValue).show();  
  } 
    return;
    });
```

After ajax call i am appending response to a div, as you can see in my code.
It's working fine in Mozila, but i don't know why it's not working in IE.
Some one have any idea why it's not working in IE.

**EDIT::: HTML IN RESPONSE VALUE:::**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/userjs/salesOrder.js"></script>
    <form id="copysalesorder"  name="copysalesorder" action="./SalesOrder.cso" method="POST">   
    <input type="hidden" id="cpnMandatory" name="cpnMandatory" value="N">

    <div class="div_portlet" >
            <div class="div_header"><span class="help"><a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:openHelp('82','82'); return false;"  ><img style="border-style: none; overflow: hidden; height: 16px; width: 16px; background-repeat: no-repeat;" src="images/help_icon_16x16.gif" alt="Help" /></a></span> Order Header Level Information</div>
                <div class="div_content">
                    <div class="innercontent_withoutscroll" >
                         <div class="fsform" >
                            <input type="hidden" id="isValid" name="isValid" value="true">
                            <input type="hidden" id="isLineValid" name="isLineValid" value="false">
                            <input type="hidden" id="region" name="region" value="EO">
....
...
...
some more html tags..
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/default.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery_cso.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/New_Order.js"></script>
<SCRIPT src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
$(function(){

    $("#dlvCRD00").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y' });
});
$('#LINEITEM_HEADER').hide();
$('#LINEITEM_HEADER_DLVINFO').hide();
$('#submitPage').hide();
$('#CopyData').hide();
</script>$('#LINEITEM_HEADER').show();
//validateOrderHeader();
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: For God's sake, keep your code clean...

Comment: Could you add a sample of the HTML inside `responseValue`?

Comment: @thirtydot-responseValue has html, with some script. i tried it by removing script, but still no luck.

Comment: how is IE behaving currently? is it showing any JS error?

Comment: is that alert you have commented out firing?

also, get rid of the return statement.

Comment: No, no error at all, i am getting responseValue in IE but simply it's not appending it to div

Comment: @Patricia- yes, that alert is firing correct response value, i removed the return statement but still no luck :(

Comment: @Vivek: Can you show what the HTML you are sending back *Actually Looks Like*? It's the most likely place for there to be a problem.

Comment: it's big html but i will try to show you...

Comment: A test link would help. Can you post a test page?

Comment: see my updates in my question..

Comment: Should this be within a script tag: `$(function(){

    $("#dlvCRD00").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y' });
});
$('#LINEITEM_HEADER').hide();
$('#LINEITEM_HEADER_DLVINFO').hide();
$('#submitPage').hide();
$('#CopyData').hide();
</script>$('#LINEITEM_HEADER').show();`? It looks like it is outside of the script block

Comment: no ..it's inside script tag,just a typo mistake

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark but try setting this:

```
return;
```

To:

```
return false;
```

Or to whatever value it should be returning.

IE is very particular when it come to javascript. If it see something it doesn't like, it quits.

Comment: You may need to pull that `return;` out of there entirely. Not sure because I don't think I'm seeing all your code here.

Comment: the code  which i have shown is the same code i have written in my js.

Comment: Ok. Then look into that `return;` to see if it is causing IE issues.

Comment: i removed the return statement but still no luck

Comment: Well, not seeing what checkSessionExpiry is doing. Have you tried running it without that if statement?

Comment: that check is, just to check session expired or not, i tried without it too. same result.